# I want to style inputs inside a div with html

Tags: html, css

edit: I can only access to the html of the div with the id

I want to do something similar to this but i can't access to css file due to my companies setup. I need to do this from HTML without css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#fileView_ctl01_D_STRT input {
  background-color: yellow;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id = "fileView_ctl01_D_STRT" class="intro">
<div>
<div>
  <input>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"i can't access to css file due to my companies setup."* - then how are we supposed to help? What is it you are expecting us to do? If you don't have access to the CSS its unlikely that you have access to the HTML.

Comment: This code works, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Give your input a name or class

Comment: I think you can use bootstrapCDN and use classes from it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ but i really don't know what you are trying to achieve. Good Luck

Comment: I can add style to the div element with id. I can't access other parts

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

*"I need to do this from HTML without css"*

I'm assuming for some reason you cannot use style blocks `<style></style>` in your html, e.g. in some email contexts.

You can overcome this by using inline style `style="background-color:yellow;"`

```
<body>
<div id = "fileView_ctl01_D_STRT" class="intro">
<div>
<div>
  <input style="background-color:yellow;">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit based on Javascript**

*"thanks but I can only edit the html of the div with the id"*

So this is the javascript that you can insert into the html code.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#fileView_ctl01_D_STRT input");
input.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<div id = "fileView_ctl01_D_STRT" class="intro">
<div>
<div>
  <input>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are inserting into the html text directly, you need to put them within the `<script></script>` block before adding them *at the bottom of the html just before `</body>`*:

```
...
<script>
    let input = document.querySelector("#fileView_ctl01_D_STRT input");
    input.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks but I can only edit the html of the div with the id , so this doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can handle this, but it kind of depends on what you mean by saying you can't use CSS. The HTML is pretty much always styled with CSS. But you can add CSS a few different ways.

1. **Inline style:** This is what I suspect you might need. Place a style attribute in the div and provide it with the appropriate directions. Example:

`<div id = "fileView_ctl01_D_STRT" style="background-color: yellow;">`

2. **An internal stylesheet:** As you've demonstrated above, you can embed an internal stylesheet.

```
    <style>
         #fileView_ctl01_D_STRT input {
         background-color: yellow;
    }
    </style>
```

3. **Javascript:** Finally, you can control styles with Javascript. You have to grab the element you want to style, for example, with the id you've assigned, and apply a style to it. Just as chatnoir has demonstrated:

`<script>
    let input = document.querySelector("#fileView_ctl01_D_STRT input");
    input.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
</script>`

This code can be in a separate, external file that you call to in the HTML via the "src" attribute.

Without CSS, you're pretty much limited to this stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951731/7055314.