# How do I modify the size of a button (and the text inside) in HTML5 without using any form of CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: html, web

I need to create a website and I would like to increase the size of the buttons because it looks really really bad.

I'm not allowed to use any form of CSS or JavaScript for this project and the solutions I found so far all use CSS.

I've tried inserting the buttons into a table but that didn't do anything to help me and all the solutions I found on the internet either don't work or use CSS

Comment: the style of html elements is given by css properties. What do you mean you can't use css? you meant css rules? css files? not even inline style of elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling html text without CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949198/styling-html-text-without-css)

Comment: @Diego Not a very helpful duplicate, almost all answers use *inline* CSS which is also CSS.

Comment: @PeterB I was naive and considered only the accepted answer that actually explains what can be done without using css. Anyway it's more narrow than what's asked here because its focus is on text mostly. I don't know... I felt it was worth mentioning. This question looks like a challenge and there are some under the hood that maybe if known could better help give more meaninful suggestions. Using the table itself was some trick to get the result (for example)

Comment: @Diego D I can't use any sort of CSS. I can't tell you very much because I don't know CSS and barely know basic HTML. The jist of it is that I have to make this dinamic website only using HTML (and SQL and PHP for databases and server stuffrespectively )and nothing else because my teacher said that if we use any form of CSS or JavaScript he fails us on the spot - so it's not really my choice...

Comment: I don't know what to say. If you are expected to deal with it without css, just don't use it and ignore the whole styling factor. If you have requirements to style things in a certain manner, go as far as you can with what you are expected to know, to add style somehow. As a user suggested in his answer, one of the many ways to affect the size of the button, using html only ***as you asked***, was embedding inside different h1, h2... elements. Your question doesn't have the elements to go any further than this. And actually it pretty answered to your exact request!

Comment: @Diego D Thank you! I did what that other answer said and it worked really well. Not using CSS isn't my choice - I don't have a choice for that matter - I mustn't use it if I'm to pass this class.

Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: if the answer of that user helped you solving your problem please take the time to accept the answer

Comment: Of course! I just don't know how... I only see buttons for running/copying code the code snippet, Sharing, Editing, Following or to Add a comment. Could you tell me what exactly lay I'm looking for please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use header elements like `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc. Semantically it may not be very 'clean' to use in this way (you *are not* creating headers as one would do in e.g. a publication), but I'm afraid there's not much else.

```html
<button>Standard size</button><br />
<br />
<button><h1>Using h1</h1></button>
<button><h2>Using h2</h2></button>
<button><h3>Using h3</h3></button>
<button><h4>Using h4</h4></button>
```